# Grouping bookmarks in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

On the bookmarks view of Visual Studio IDE, we can create folders to group saved bookmarks. But in Android Studio, it doesn't seem possible to group bookmarks. I don't even realize how to effectively use the Bookmark Mnemonic feature in Android Studio. Alternatively, is it possible to write a plugin for grouping saved bookmarks? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported at the moment, related requests:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56423
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134479
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152521

A plug-in is possible.